# JQuery carousel slideshow issue

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, internet-explorer-7, carousel

I am totally stumped...

Can anyone advise why the following carousel/slideshow (at top of template) works in IE8 & IE9, but not IE7?
In IE7, it just stacks the images one on top of the other for some reason.
Do I have a conflict or some JS that won't work in IE7?

(http://)212.113.141.98/~c2cj25v2

I need this to work in IE7.

I am using the http://foundation.zurb.com in my Joomla template.

Any advice/help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check the way in which js files are included..might be a jquery conflict case. use jQuery.noConflict(); for js conflict case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your JavaScript:

> Uncaught exception: TypeError: '$('mcsignupSubmit7677').addEvent' is not a function

Fix that and it should fix the IE7 issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you point me in the right direction - which JS file?

Comment: looks like it's inline - just under `Newsletter Signup` in the code.